# For which $n$ is $37|1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I want to understand the solution to part b) of this problem that I have posted below.  Part a) was solved by showing that $x^2+x+1 | x^{2n}+x^n+1$ iff $3 \nmid n$.  Since we are using the expression of part a) evaluated at $x=10$ to prove the divisibility of $37|1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1$ it seems to me that we can only conclude for which $n$,  $3\cdot 37|1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{n-times}1$.  Since the digital sum on the right is always divisible by $3$ how can we conclude for which $n$ the expression is divisible by $37$

[image]

---

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: What's your question.  You asked a question.  Explained everything you knew.  And posted an answer that gave the complete answer in coherent explanation.  So.... what's your question.

Comment: I said that my interpretation of the solution was we only proved divisibility by $111$ not $37$, which is what the question is asking

Comment: $37|111$ so if $111|M$ then $37|M$.

Comment: Did you do something wrong?  Shouldn't it be "$x^2+x+1 \nmid x^{2n}+x^n+1$ if and only if $3\mid n$"?  For every integer $n$ divisible by $3$, $$x^{2n}+x^n+1\equiv 3\pmod{x^2+x+1}\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski In the book it has $x^2+x+1 | x^{2n}+x^n+1$ iff $3\nmid n$.  The solution proved it by checking each case: $n=3k$, $n=3k+1$ and $n=3k+2$.  Using the property that $x^3-1 | x^{3m}-1$, and factoring using difference of cubes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the books results (too early).  But since $3|M$ we know $111|M \iff 37|M$ because $111=3*37$ and $jk|M \implies j|M$ and $k|M$.

Comment: @johnfowles  Then the book says the same thing I did.  You didn't write it correctly in your question statement.  Take a look at the first paragraph of your question.

Comment: @fleablood I forgot that property.  That clears it up

Comment: So what's happening here? The question is answered or not? Are we supposed to read through these comments to find that out? It seems to me that we can take this question off people's radar two hours ago...

Comment: @Mason should i delete it?  my question was answered but perhaps i should leave it up somehow in case others are interested in the questions and commentary